# handle static resource (SVG image) in Vue & Vite

Tags: vue.js, vite

If I use the commented code segment in the `volumeSrc` method, the volume icon will not be displayed correctly and an error will be reported in the browser.

`GET http://localhost:5173/icons/volume/slience.svg 404 (Not Found)`

while the list svg will display correctly

```js
<script>
const volume = {
  slience: {
    id: 0,
    src: "./icons/volume/slience.svg",
    alt: "slience",
  },
  // ...
};

const playerState = ref({
  settings: {
    volume: volume.slience,
    list: false,
  },
});

const volumeSrc = computed(() => {
  // return playerState.value.settings.volumeSrc.src;
  const path = new URL(playerState.value.settings.volume.src, import.meta.url);
  return path.href;
});

const volumeAlt = computed(() => {
  return playerState.value.settings.volume.alt;
});
</script>

<template>
    <div class="player-settings-btn list">
        <img src="./icons/list.svg" alt="list" />
    </div>
    <div class="player-settings-btn volume" @click="toggleVolume">
        <img :src="volumeSrc" :alt="volumeAlt" />
    </div>
</template>
```

I found a solution in [vite docs about static source](https://cn.vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#new-url-url-import-meta-url), and I fix in code above.

In my opinion, this solution is achieved by using the URL function to obtain the absolute path of the icon. However, I don't understand why I can't use a relative path to do that...

the similar question I have checked is about Webpack, so I wonder if there is an explanation about how the resource and code was handled when develop

thanks for every replies~